# Why does naming a variable "NU" instead of e.g. "ANU" change the output of my UMAT? (Abaqus/Fortran)

Tags: fortran, abaqus

I am starting to learn how to write UMATs in Abaqus, so I took the most simple example, which is linear elasticity (Hooke's law), and implemented it. I tested it on a 3D-rectangular body with a fixed bottom and a displacement boundary on top (tension).

When I use the following code...

```
SUBROUTINE UMAT(STRESS,STATEV,DDSDDE,SSE,SPD,SCD,
     1 RPL,DDSDDT,DRPLDE,DRPLDT,
     2 STRAN,DSTRAN,TIME,DTIME,TEMP,DTEMP,PREDEF,DPRED,CMNAME,
     3 NDI,NSHR,NTENS,NSTATV,PROPS,NPROPS,COORDS,DROT,PNEWDT,
     4 CELENT,DFGRD0,DFGRD1,NOEL,NPT,LAYER,KSPT,KSTEP,KINC)
!
      INCLUDE 'ABA_PARAM.INC'
!
      CHARACTER*80 CMNAME
      DIMENSION STRESS(NTENS),STATEV(NSTATV),
     1 DDSDDE(NTENS,NTENS),DDSDDT(NTENS),DRPLDE(NTENS),
     2 STRAN(NTENS),DSTRAN(NTENS),TIME(2),PREDEF(1),DPRED(1),
     3 PROPS(NPROPS),COORDS(3),DROT(3,3),DFGRD0(3,3),DFGRD1(3,3)
     
!   elastic UMAT

      PARAMETER (ONE=1.0D0, TWO=2.0D0)
        E = PROPS(1)
        NU = PROPS(2)
        ALAMBDA = E/(ONE+NU)/(ONE-TWO*NU)
        BLAMBDA = ONE-NU
        CLAMBDA = (ONE-TWO*NU)/TWO 
        DO I=1,NTENS
          DO J=1,NTENS
            DDSDDE(I,J)=0.0D0
          ENDDO
        ENDDO   
        DDSDDE(1,1)=(ALAMBDA*BLAMBDA)
        DDSDDE(2,2)=(ALAMBDA*BLAMBDA)
        DDSDDE(3,3)=(ALAMBDA*BLAMBDA)
        DDSDDE(4,4)=(ALAMBDA*CLAMBDA)
        DDSDDE(5,5)=(ALAMBDA*CLAMBDA)
        DDSDDE(6,6)=(ALAMBDA*CLAMBDA)
        DDSDDE(1,2)=(ALAMBDA*NU)
        DDSDDE(1,3)=(ALAMBDA*NU)
        DDSDDE(2,3)=(ALAMBDA*NU)
        DDSDDE(2,1)=(ALAMBDA*NU)
        DDSDDE(3,1)=(ALAMBDA*NU)
        DDSDDE(3,2)=(ALAMBDA*NU)
        DO I=1,NTENS
          DO J=1,NTENS
            STRESS(I)=STRESS(I)+DDSDDE(I,J)*DSTRAN(J)
          ENDDO
        ENDDO
      
      
      
      RETURN
      END
```

... the output is wrong. When I change the variable name "NU" to e.g. "ANU", the code all of a sudden gives the right solution, which is equivalent to the Abaqus Elastic Material result. This is confusing me a lot.

Does "NU" happen to be some kind of protected keyword, or am I missing some sort of declaration?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think it is a problem with the variable declaration.

When I add

```
DOUBLE PRECISION :: E, NU, ...
```

all works well.

Comment: I strongly, strongly, strongly, strongly, strongly, strongly, strongly, strongly, strongly, strongly, strongly, strongly, strongly, strongly, strongly, strongly, recommend you **always** use `Implicit None` which will force you to think more carefully about what type your variables should be, as well as avoid numerous bugs due to typos.

Comment: Ian Bush, thanks a lot. I was not even aware that I was not using the ```Implicit None``` statement, nor did I really know what it means. Reading into its meaning opened my eyes.